# Java and Firebird Embedded how to create db?

Tags: java, firebird

now i get java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:firebirdsql:embedded:f/test.fdb

i included jaybird jars with my project. please help me out
package util;

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import org.firebirdsql.gds.impl.GDSType;
import org.firebirdsql.management.FBManager;

public class FireBirdCreator {

    public FireBirdCreator() {
        FBManager manager = new FBManager(GDSType.getType("EMBEDDED"));

        try {
            manager.start();
            manager.createDatabase("f:/test.fdb", "sysdba", "masterkey");
            manager.stop();
        Connection bd = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:firebirdsql:embedded:f/test.fdb");
        Statement st = bd.createStatement();
        st.execute("create table if not exists 'TABLE1' ('name1' int, 'name2' text, 'name3' text);");
        st.execute("insert into 'TABLE1' ('name1', 'name2', 'name3') values (1, 'name1', 'name2'); ");
        st.execute("insert into 'TABLE1' ('name1', 'name2', 'name3') values (2, 'name3', 'name4'); ");
        st.execute("insert into 'TABLE1' ('name1', 'name2', 'name3') values (3, 'name5', 'name6');");
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from TABLE1");
        while (rs.next())
            {
                System.out.print  (rs.getString(1)+" ");
                System.out.print  (rs.getString(2)+" ");
                System.out.println(rs.getString(3));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        FireBirdCreator fbc = new FireBirdCreator();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your title suggests you want to create a database, while your code is only connecting to a database. Does the database exist?

Comment: thanks for answer. no it doesnt. How do i create it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message indicates that the file does not exist. The fact that it shows 'null' instead of the actual filename might be a mismatch between embedded version and Jaybird version.

To create a database you need to use the following code (and handle the exceptions it throws in a correct manner):

```
FBManager manager = new FBManager(GDSType.getType("EMBEDDED"));
manager.start();
manager.createDatabase("database.fdb", "", "");
manager.stop();
```

Also be aware that the DDL you are using to create the table is not valid Firebird SQL. You will need to use [RECREATE TABLE](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-ddl-table.html#langrefupd25-recreate-table) and Firebird does not have a type called `text`.

Full disclosure: I am one of the developers of Jaybird (the Firebird JDBC driver).